# android video chat that a toddler can't accidentally close or toggle out of

Tags: android, video-conferencing

I skype with my 15 month god-daughter semi regularly.  She gets oddly excited to see me, and insists on 'carrying' me around to play games with her.  Unfortunately as a toddler holding and playing with a smart phone she will accidentally shrink my screen, toggle out to another app, or close the connection.  When that happens she takes it to her mother and insists she reopen me (which is cute to me, as it shows me she cares that I'm on the phone and she can see me when she it carrying me around).

I would like to be able to make the chat with her a little more reliable, which means some way of getting a more toddler-proof chat client.  By that I mean video chat that is harder to close or toggle out of by accident, so she can't mess anything up by holding and playing with the screen.

Does anyone know of anything that will do this?  Either a chat engine itself, or possibly a secondary app that simply blocks accidental pressing of buttons while the app is open?

Comment: It might be important to know what Android version is running on her device. My first thought was "pinning" the chat window, which AFAIK is supported since Android 5.* and would at least avoid half of the issues without needing any additional software: she couldn't easily "swap you out" or "shrink you" ;) For details, e.g. see [How to 'Pin' apps in Android 5.0 Lollipop](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/ho-to-pin-apps-in-android-5-lollipop/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this a little too hard.  Rather then finding a chat app which did this we instead found a screen locking app, which the mother could turn on after video chatting me with a regular app and before handing it to my goddaughter.  The app prevents any touchscreen interactions until a user does a particular (hard to do accidentally) swipe to disable the lock.  I'm told my friend also used this in conjunction with streaming video app to give her daughter something to watch during long car rides.

I'm not sure which app she ultimately used to lock the screen.  However I originally sent her a list of a few different app, like [these](https://www.guidingtech.com/55205/disable-screen-touch-controls-android-toddlers/).  It turns out there are a large number of available apps like this to choose from.